# Weird behaviour with htaccess RewriteRule (puts ?url= at the end in the address bar)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, uri

Currently i'm working on a webpage for my upcoming twitch bot. While doing this, i encountered a somewhat weird problem, or at least a behaviour i didn't expect and which i investigated the last 24 hours to narrow it down.

I have an .htaccess file in my webpage root folder, which contains

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

php_flag display_errors on

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and its totally working fine, when entering an url into the address bar. But when i click a link on my webpage, it strangely appends ?url= to the address. So if i enter 'https://blockinfo.thatsnasu.dev/docs/' manually, it loads the page and i'm happy. But if i just click on the link on the main page https://blockinfo.thatsnasu.dev (which is just a

```html
<a href="/docs">Documentation</a>
```

it transforms the url in the address bar to 'https://blockinfo.thatsnasu.dev/docs/?url=docs' and i dont know really why. Like i said, i investigated this, and what i found out so far is that it only happens, if a folder with the same name as the target address exists in the root dir of my websource. In my source all links look like the stated above, so thats not the issue. I tried adding a dummy link without a corresponding folder, clicked it, address looks fine. After adding a folder with the same name, the ?url= appending happens, so my bet is, that something with my rewrite rule seems to be off. Sure, i could fix that by just renaming the folders to something different, so there would be no folder that has the same name as the link target, but i'd rather like to understand why this happens and how i can fix it cleanly. I never encountered this issue with RewriteRules before, since i normally would make seperate vhosts in apache for the different sections of the page (one vhost for the normal webpage, one for the documentation under https://docs.domain/ and one for the api, sitting under https://api.domain/), but since this project is rather small i wanted to pack it all up in one vhost, since everything else seemed overkill to me.

For anyone who has questions about my code: the source is public on my github ( https://github.com/thatsnasu/blockinfo-web )

Oh quick sidenote: on my Ubuntu laptop this strange behaviour does not occur. But i guess thats not related to this problem, since on the Ubuntu Laptop of one of my friends it happens, on the Windows machine of another friend it happens, on my windows tower it happens and on several mobile devices it also happens. So i just accept that my laptop seems to be a special snowflake.

Thanks for reading this far c:

Edit: changed the pseudo links to actual links, so anyone helping me investigate this has the possibility to take a look at the actual page and its behaviour.

Comment: If you really requested `/docs/` via your browser address bar, but your links are actually just pointing to `/docs` - then this likely has something to do with the automatic trailing slash redirect performed by mod_dir, and the fact that your RewriteCond tests for an existing _file_ only.

Comment: it doesn't matter if i call https://blockinfo.thatsnasu.dev/docs with or without the trailing slash, it gets appended automatically.

Comment: Also maybe noteworthy: I removed the rewrites for directories and symlinks, since calling https://blockinfo.thatsnasu.dev/docs resulted in the browser showing the actual folder content instead of rewriting it. I'm not sure if denying the direct access to the sub directories would eliminate this, or if it would just give me a "403 Forbidden".

Comment: _"it gets appended automatically"_ - that would be mod_dir doing its job then, according to the `DirectorySlash` directive. _"since calling blockinfo.thatsnasu.dev/docs resulted in the browser showing the actual folder content"_ - without the slash? But then `DirectorySlash` would have to be off _already_ ...? Make sure you are not getting fooled by any redirects the browser might have cached - test in a private tab.

Comment: even in a private tab it does this weird things. i mean you can try it yourself if you like, thats why i put in the actual links in my post, since i thought it might be easier that way. Also i maybe should state that i never changed anything on the apache configuration except enabling mod_rewrite. So except mod_rewrite its a plain vanilla apache installation, running on latest version provided by apt on my raspbian

Comment: Oh, and the actual folder content only gets displayed if i add the ```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d``` back in, which kind of makes sense, because it detects there is a folder and it then should not rewrite it, so the browser will display the folder contents if accessible